# React: I want to make a function that renders a new component with onClick EVERY TIME it's clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a kanban board. I'm trying to create a button that adds a new card.

So far I've been able to create a conditional with states that will essentially toggle a card. It'll appear when clicked and disappear when the button is clicked again, which is not what I want so I started over.

This is the function I want to call onClick. The message logs in the console when the button is clicked but the KanBanCard component is unresponsive and there are no errors.

```
newCard() {
        console.log("New card being displayed");

        return (
            <div>
                <KanBanCard />
            </div>
        )

    }
```

My button rendering:

```
return (
            <main>
                <button onClick={this.newCard} className="card-add">
                    +
                </button>
            </main>
            
        )
```

Comment: Hi, shanicunn; how about `{this.newCard}` to `{this.newCard()}`?  You need to indicate it's a function.  Also...  That'll get you further, but, you may need to do more.  Why is onClick returning an element?  It's supposed to change state, and then render is supposed to consider that state, to determine how it looks.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger  no that's incorrect. the way OP has it is passing the function reference, the way you have written it will call the function on render not on `onClick`

Comment: Ah, good point, in that case, I'd consider the second thing I said, about it returning an element and not changin state.

Comment: yea, it makes no sense for an eventhandler to return anything at all actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not rendering because you are not rendering the new `<KanBanCard />` that you are creating. You cannot return it because it will return it to the `onClick` method. What you can do is create a state that holds the list of Kanban cards and update that when the button is clicked. Make sure you render that list. It would look like this:

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            kanbanList: [],
        }
    }

    newCard() {
        const newCard = <div><KanBanCard /></div>;
        this.setState({ kanbanList: [...this.state.kanbanList, newCard] });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <main>
                <button onClick={this.newCard} className="card-add">+</button>
                <div className="cards-holder">
                    {this.state.kanbanList.map(card => card)}
                </div>
            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thank you so much. All I had to do was use the arrow function in my onClick and it worked just like you said!